# Setting Default Parameter value for a multi-select text parameter in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

We have an issue trying to set a multi-select parameter in ssrs-2016 via the Manage->Parameters menu in ssrs-2016 itself.  parameter has available values, it works in the report normally. but when going into set some defaults via the ssrs website, the available listing is blank.  is there something that I am missing?

[image: Set Parameters Blank Drop down]

[image: Active report Drop down]

What I find interesting is that the rendering of the list in the report looks very much like it hasn't changed from ssrs-2008 r2.  I have tried creating a new report with just a single report parameter and I get the same thing.

Comment: I never tried setting defaults using the web interface. Can you not set them in design and redeploy your report? If you do this though, be aware that defaults are not overwritten (certainly not in earlier versions) so it's safer to delete the report and redeploy it (or deploy as a new report to be on the safe side)

Comment: We want to use this report with different defaults for different people and didn't want to deploy multiple versions of the same report just to get different defaults for a single parameter.  That may be a workaround in the short term though.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the default in, like with the other parameters by clicking in the location circled, typing it in, and hit enter.

If your looking to see all the drop down options, you will have to run the report to get those, and once you have one picked out, type it in, like described above.

Hope this helps. 
[image]

Comment: While that may work for people who understand ssrs etc, that is not going to work for the average user that we want to have set up their own subscriptions.